# grep for contents AFTER line break

Tags: linux, bash, grep

My file `sms.txt`:

```
1 sender: 887645651201059711697
date:   15/02/04,08:07:08

Maaf, pulsa Anda tidak cukup untuk mengaktifkan Pkt Super Ngebut 11GB, 30hr, Rp55rb. Ayo isi pulsa di XL Center, ATM, Minimarket, Inet, m-Banking. Info 817
```

How do I print the contents of the sms only? So I want the output to be like this:

```
Maaf, pulsa Anda tidak cukup untuk mengaktifkan Pkt Super Ngebut 11GB, 30hr, Rp55rb. Ayo isi pulsa di XL Center, ATM, Minimarket, Inet, m-Banking. Info 817
```

I tried `grep '\n.*' sms.txt` but didn't work.

Comment: Do your `sms.txt` only have one message, or may there be multiple messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that this does what you want:

```
$ awk '/^$/{f=1} f && /./{print;f=0}' sms.txt
Maaf, pulsa Anda tidak cukup untuk mengaktifkan Pkt Super Ngebut 11GB, 30hr, Rp55rb. Ayo isi pulsa di XL Center, ATM, Minimarket, Inet, m-Banking. Info 817
```

#### How it works

- `/^$/{f=1}`

  Every time we encounter an empty line, the flag `f` is set to 1.
- `f && /./{print;f=0}`

  If the flag `f` is non-zero and the current line is not empty, then print the current line and reset `f` to zero.

#### Alternatives

As suggested by Jotne in the comments, here are two other `awk` commands that accomplish the same goal:

```
awk '!/./{f=1} f && /./{print;f=0}' sms.txt

awk '!NF{f=1} f && NF{print;f=0}' sms.txt
```

Comment: This is the more portable of the two suggested answers.

Comment: I would not have used `/^$/` and `/./`.  You could have used `awk '!/./{f=1} f && /./{print;f=0}'`, but I would have used  `awk '!NF{f=1} f && NF{print;f=0}'`

Comment: @Jotne Good ideas.  I added both of those to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try sed:

```
sed -r '/^[0-9]+ sender:/d;/^date:\s+/d;/^\s*$/d' sms.txt >textonly.txt
```

lines starting with patterns matching the date and sender headers will be deleted as well as lines containing only whitespace.

Comment: doesn't work, I edited my question to make it easier to solve, please take a look at it again.

Comment: no, the output is exactly the same as the original file

Answer (score 0):

**using sed**

```
sed -r '/^( *[0-9]* sender:| *date:| *$)/d' sms.txt
```

**EDIT** : or

```
sed -nr '/^( *[0-9]* sender:| *date:| *$)/! {p}' sms.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you could do the following using grep.

```
grep -Eo '^[^:]+$' sms.txt
```

Comment: That's coincidental -- the message could very well contain a colon in the text.